# VS Code clang formatting inserting backslashes, indents, and newlines with comments

Tags: c, clang, vscode-extensions, clang-format

I've recently picked up embedded programming in VS Code and have been trying to set up the autoformatting to work as intended. I'm using clang and currently using the following settings:

`"C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "{BasedOnStyle: WebKit, BreakBeforeBraces: Attach, IndentWidth: 4, TabWidth: 4, UseTab: Never, ColumnLimit: 0, PointerAlignment: Right"`

Seems to be when there are comments involved, it adds backslashes, new lines, and random indnetations. I've tested out using this header file:

[Before formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BfQH.png)

[After formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBXQu.png)

How can I remove these strange inserts and backslashes that are being inserted? Ideally I want it to look something like the original. I suspect that it may be due to a format setting that I can tweak however I have spent hours looking for it and can't find anything neither online or in the setting. Any help poiting in the right would greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is clear and concise, however in order to help users answer your question, please avoid posting code as images - you can copy and paste them into code blocks instead.

Comment: I believe the correct setting would be `C_Cpp.clang_format_style`.

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome. I thought I would add the photos since I wasn't sure if copying the code over in code blocks would capture the issue I was having, but I will definitely be using them in the future. Also it seems that `C_Cpp.clang_format_style` isn;t doing much unfortunately, the same issue persists.